# modify data notifications after the app is terminated // Android, Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want modify data notifications after the app is terminated.
How can I do?

The function I want: I want to localize the notification.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use

flutter_local_notifications:

by this you can create your custom notification

Comment: I need work when the app was killed.

Comment: Than use work manager for this